# Find all natural numbers for which $3\binom{2n}{n+1}=2\binom{2n+1}{n-1}$ holds true

Tags: combinatorics

I end up getting a quadratic equasion with no natural answers, so I am probably wrong.

(Dont know if the tag is right, its part of the combinatorics section in my book)

Comment: Even if it is wrong, show us what'd u do, it'll help us help u :)

Comment: Well, I wrote $\binom{2n}{n+1}$ as $\binom{2n}{n-1}$ ($\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$) and when I expanded the form, a lot of stuff cancelled out leaving $3=2*(2n+1)(n+3)$, which is a quadratic equasion with no natural answers, afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea;
$$ 3 \times {2n \choose n+1} = 2 \times { 2n+1 \choose n-1}$$

$$ 3 \times \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!(n-1)!} = 2 \times \frac{(2n+1)!}{(n-1)!(n+2)!}$$

Cancelling gives:
$$ 3  = 2 \times \frac{(2n+1)}{(n+2)}$$
and thus $$3n+ 6 = 4n+2$$
and so $n=4$.

We can check:
$$ 3 \times {8 \choose 5} = 3\times 56 = 168$$
and
$$ 2 \times { 9 \choose 3} = 2\times 84 = 168$$

Answer (score 2):

$$3\,\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!\,(n-1)!}=2\,\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n-1)!\,(n+2)!}$$
simplifies to $3=2\,\dfrac{2n+1}{n+2}$, which is not a quadratic equation…

Comment: I can see that now. I did the simplyfing wrong. Thanks!